# Why case..when get a table scan ? how to workarround

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

When I use *CASE .. WHEN .. END* I get an *index scan* less efficient than the *index seek*.

I have complex business rules I need to use the *CASE*, is there any workaround ?

Query A:

```
    select * from [dbo].[Mobile]
    where((
    CASE 
    where ([MobileNumber] = (LTRIM(RTRIM('987654321'))))
    END
    ) = 1)
```

This query gets an *index scan* and 199 logical reads.

Query B:

```
    select * from [dbo].[Mobile]
    where ([MobileNumber] = (LTRIM(RTRIM('987654321'))))
```

This query gets an *index seek* and 122 logical reads.

Comment: Because the `CASE` isn't SARGable. Why do you want to use a `CASE` expression like that on the column in the `WHERE` in the first place? Also why do you have `RTRIM`/`LTRIM` wrapped around a string literal with no leading/trailing spaces?

Comment: The `CASE` in the question is not currently valid. It is `CASE WHEN` not `CASE WHERE` and you have forgotten to return `1` from it. When fixed though SQL Server does not try and crack that apart to make it a seekable predicate. You will always get a scan for that type of thing.

Comment: "is there any workaround ?" - You already have query b. So what kind of workaround are you looking for?

Comment: the correct script is : select * from [dbo].[Mobile]
 where((
 CASE 
 When ([Mobile] = (LTRIM(RTRIM('123456789')))) THEN cast(1 as bit)
 END
 ) = 1)

Comment: Why are you using LTRIM/RTRIM on a string literal that doesn't need trimming?

Comment: Why do you have a CASE expression at all? Seems it should just be `WHERE Mobile = '123456789';`

Comment: I'm using case to illustrate the problem, because inhouse I have queries with same issue with complex business logic in the case statements.

Comment: As you haven't given a realistic example of your actual problem it isn't possible for us to see if you have any hope of getting index seeks in your real case. But even in simple cases the product won't do it for you. It is up to you to write the query in a way that works well with the product.

Answer (score 3):

For the table

```
CREATE TABLE #T(X CHAR(1) PRIMARY KEY);
```

And the query

```
SELECT *
FROM   #T
WHERE  CASE WHEN X = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1;
```

It is apparent without that much thought that the only circumstances in which the `CASE` expression evaluates to `1` are when  `X = 'A'` and that the query has the same semantics as

```
SELECT *
FROM   #T
WHERE  X = 'A';
```

However the first query will get a scan and the second one a seek.

The SQL Server optimiser will try all sorts of *relational* transformations on queries but will not even attempt to rearrange *expressions* such as `CASE WHEN X = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1` to express it as an `X =`  expression so it can perform an index seek on it.

It is up to the query writer to write their queries in such a way that they are [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).

There is no workaround to get an index seek on column `MobileNumber` with your existing `CASE` predicate. You just need to express the condition differently (as in your example `B`).

Potentially you could create a computed column with the `CASE` expression and index that - and you could then see an index seek on the new column. However this is unlikely to be useful to you as I assume in reality the mobile number `987654321` is  dynamic and not something to be hardcoded into a column used by an index.

Comment: The case issue depends on sql version ?

Comment: @lumiga - No. There is no current version of SQL Server that will take your CASE expression and make it into something that can use an index seek.

Answer (score 2):

After cleaning up and fixing your code, you have a `WHERE` which is `boolean`  expression based around  a `CASE`.

As mentioned by @MartinSmith, there is simply no way SQL Server will re-arrange this. It does not do the kind of dynamic slicing that would allow it to re-arrange the first query into the second version.

```
select *
from [dbo].[Mobile]
where
    CASE 
    WHEN [MobileNumber] = LTRIM(RTRIM('987654321'))
    THEN 1
    END
 = 1
```

You may ask: the second version also has an expression in it, why does this not also get a scan?

```
select *
from [dbo].[Mobile]
where [MobileNumber] = LTRIM(RTRIM('987654321'))
```

The reason is that what SQL Server *can* recognize is that `LTRIM(RTRIM('987654321'))` is a deterministic constant expression: it does not change depending on runtime settings, nor on the result of in-row calculations.

Therefore, it can optimize by calculating it at compile time. The query therefore becomes this under the hood, which can be used against an index on `MobileNumber`.

```
select *
from [dbo].[Mobile]
where [MobileNumber] = '987654321'
```

Comment: The case issue depends on sql version ?

Comment: No why would you think that?